# Configuring GIT with Hudson

Tags: git, hudson

I am naive to HUDSON and GIT, i followed some tutorials and tried to configure hudson and git.

Settings that i have done till now,

1. Set the path to git executable
2. created a empty local repository using mysysgit UI.
3. create a new job with git as source code management,

   - URL of Repository:  `file:///c:/GitShare/Test/MyRepo`
   - Branch Specifier :  `master`
4. save the file and run the build

I got the following error:

```
Started by user anonymous
Checkout:workspace / C:\Hudson\jobs\Test1\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1ed8c3
Using strategy: Default
Checkout:workspace / C:\Hudson\jobs\Test1\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1ed8c3
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from file:///c:/GitShare/Test/MyRepo
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
ERROR:  (Underlying report) : Error performing command: C:\Git\bin fetch -t file:///c:/GitShare/Test/MyRepo +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Cannot run program "C:\Git\bin" (in directory "C:\Hudson\jobs\Test1\workspace"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:824)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:782)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.gerRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:782)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:568)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1218)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:507)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:424)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1367)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
```

**UPDATE**

thanks for replying, i had already given all the permission to user, and had specified the path i.e. "C:\Git\bin\git.exe".. after working around i am able to connect to a local repository through Hudson but when i tried to connect to another local repository i am getting  the following error.

Started by user anonymous
Checkout:workspace / C:\Hudson\jobs\Job1\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@84a6c0
Using strategy: Default
Checkout:workspace / C:\Hudson\jobs\Job1\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@84a6c0
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git://160.110.149.132/GIT_Repo
ERROR: Nothing to do
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: Job1 #3 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE

I guess repository is not initialized properly, can you please tell me the steps to create local repository and to publish it publicly.

Steps i have followed to create a repository:
1. open Git Bash Shell,
2. navigate to the repo folder which is having project to be published, and typed "git init" command.

Question 2:

if my repository is located on "c:/GitShare/Repo".
This "Repo" folder contains a ".git" and Project(to be published) folders.

Than what will be URL for the repository?

Comment: Here's the important line of your error message: `Cannot run program "C:\Git\bin" (in directory "C:\Hudson\jobs\Test1\workspace"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have your paths and permissions set correctly?

- When asked for the path to the git executable, Hudson may want you to specify a full path including the .exe filename, and not just `C:/Git/bin` (which is just the folder it's in).
- Alternatively, whatever user Hudson is running as may not have access to that directory.